# Library System query

Tags: java, arraylist, system

I am having problems with the search feature of my library system project. The code I have so far allows you to see if the book is 'available' or 'not available'. I would like to make my system also be able to display all the information on the book, including the number of copies, it's ISBN etc. 
This is the code I used for searching if the book is available or not.

```
public String searchTitle(String titleSearch) {
    if (titleSearch == null)
        return "\n No Books Avaliable ";
    for (int i = 0; i < collection.size(); i++){
        if (titleSearch.equalsIgnoreCase(collection.get(i).getTitle())) {
            return "\n Book Avaliable";
        }
    }
    return "\n No Books Avaliable "; //reachable only if no book found
}
```

This is also the code I have used in my `Book` class:

```
public Book(int isbn, String author, String title, String genre, int numcopies) {
    this.isbn = isbn;
    this.author = author;
    this.title = title;
    this.genre = genre;
    this.numcopies = numcopies;
}

public int getISBN() {
    return isbn;
}

public String getAuthor() {
    return author;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public String getGenre() {
    return genre;
}

public String toString() {
    return "\nISBN: " + isbn + "\nAuthor: " + author + "\nTitle: " + title +
 "\nGenre: " + genre + "\nNumber Of Copies " + numcopies +"\n ";
}
```

Comment: Can you explain more about your issue ?

Comment: So add another method that returns a Book object from your collection given a title.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. Currently when I search for a book it says either "available" or "not available". How ever I want to add a feature which if "available" is displayed, it also displays all the information on the book. e.g. The books ISBN, the author, how many copies of the book are in the library.

Comment: If you add books to `collection` somewhere, either manually or from a database or other file is not clear. The code you posted is ok, but it's not the code we need to identify why your code basicly gives a nullpointerexception or how `Book` objects are being created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand you correctly;

```
    if(titleSearch.equalsIgnoreCase(collection.get(i).getTitle())){
        return "\n Book Avaliable";
    }
```

in this part of the code you can return the result for to string method in book class easily. It is like returning the string "\n Book Avaliable".

Remember that you can call to string function like `collection.get(i).toString()`

Or simply the code will be like;

```
if(titleSearch.equalsIgnoreCase(collection.get(i).getTitle())){
        return collection.get(i).toString();
    }
```

Comment: When I put that bit of code into my project, it says "Variable toString cannot be found".

Comment: oh sorry I forgot the parenthesis it should be collection.get(i).toString();